# Flutter Widget Testing for BlocBuilder Widgets

Tags: flutter, testing, dependency-injection, bloc, widget-test-flutter

I have a Widget which uses bloc builder to map the different state of widget.

```
class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocBuilder<NewsBloc, NewsState>(builder: (context, state) {
          return state.map(
            .....
          );
        });
      }
    ....
    }
```

The `BodyWidget` is created in a Widget with BlocProvider.

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          getIt<NewsBloc>()..add(const NewsEvent.fetchNewsData()),
      child: BodyWidget(),
    );
  }
....
}
```

And the NewsBloc is defined as

```
@injectable
class NewsBloc extends Bloc<NewsEvent, NewsState> {
  final GetNews getNews;
  NewsBloc({
    @required this.getNews,
  }) : super(const _Initial());

  @override
  Stream<NewsState> mapEventToState(
    NewsEvent event,
  ) async* { ... }
}
```

I am using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) and [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) for Dependency Injection.

Now I am trying to write a simple widget test for `BodyWidget` and I am not so sure how to inject all these dependency in test.

```
class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}

class MockNewsBloc extends Mock implements NewsBloc {}

void main() {
  ForYouNewsTab _widget;
  MockBuildContext _context;
  NewsBloc _newsBloc;

  Widget makeTestableWidgets({Widget child}) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        // body: BlocProvider(
        //   create: (_context) => getIt<NewsBloc>(),
        //   child: child,
        // ),
        body: child,
      ),
    );
  }

  setUp(() {
    _context = MockBuildContext();
    _widget = ForYouNewsTab();
  });

  test('ForYouNewsTab is sub class of StatelessWidget', () {
    expect(_widget, isA<StatelessWidget>());
  });

  testWidgets('should return sized box for initial state',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidgets(child: _widget));
  });
}
```

I did search in stackoverflow, but could not found a solution that works form me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by following very basic steps. Not so sure if its the right way. Anyway if anyone ever comes to the same problem, it might help them.

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

  //added line
  final NewsBloc newsBloc;

  const MainPage({
    Key key, 
    @required this. newsBloc,
  })

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      // changed line
      // create: (context) => getIt<NewsBloc>()..add(const NewsEvent.fetchNewsData()),
      create: (context) => newsBloc..add(const NewsEvent.fetchNewsData()),
      child: BodyWidget(),
    );
  }

  ....

 }
```

Now in my test case I can create MockNewsBloc and inject it easily to the MainPage when it is under testing.